# The sum of infinite fours: $\sqrt{4^0+\sqrt{4^1+ \sqrt{4^2+ \dots}}}=?$

Tags: calculus, nested-radicals

> $\sqrt{4^0+\sqrt{4^1+\sqrt{4^2+\sqrt{4^3+\cdots}}}}=?$

I found this problem in a book. I tried to solve this but couldn't. Using calculator, I found the value close to $2$. But how can this problem be solved with proper procedure?

Comment: These questions seem similar: [Nested Square Roots $5^0+\sqrt{5^1+\sqrt{5^2+\sqrt{5^4+\sqrt\dots}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61012) and [Determine $x$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{1+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x^2…+\sqrt{x^n}}}} = 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1659502). (Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%7B4%5E0%2B%5Csqrt%7B4%5E1%2B%20%5Csqrt%7B4%5E2%2B%20...%7D%7D%7D%24&p=1). More tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265))

Comment: It would be nice if some sort of recursive relation could be generated in order to express, say, the finite radical going up to $4^n$ in terms of the previous radicals. But I guess that might be too easy and too much to hope for  (plus I had no luck in finding one). :/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3396730/on-some-infinite-nested-square-root/3396941#3396941

Comment: Is it solvable if you take powers of 5 instead of 4? @MartinSleziak

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that:
$2^2=1+3$, $3^2=4+5$, $5^2=16+9$, $9^2=64+17$, ...

Therefore
$$2=\sqrt{4^0+3}$$
$$2=\sqrt{4^0+\sqrt{4^1+ 5}}$$
$$...$$
$$2=\sqrt{4^0+\sqrt{4^1+ \sqrt{4^2+ \sqrt{4^3+17}}}}$$
$$...$$
$$...$$

Let $F_n=\sqrt{4^0+\sqrt{4^1+ \sqrt{4^2+ \sqrt{4^3+...}}}}$ where the sequence terminates after $n$ square roots. 
For positive numbers $a$ and $b$, we have $\sqrt{a+b}<\sqrt{a}+\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}$ and therefore

$$F_n<2<F_n+\frac{2^n+1}{2^n(1+2+...+2^{n-1})}$$
Hence $F_n$ converges to 2.

Answer (score 4):

Take $f(x,n)=x+2^n$. We can see that;
$$\begin{aligned}
 f(x,n) &= \sqrt{2^{2n}+x\left(x+2^{n+1}\right)} \\
 &= \sqrt{2^{2n}+xf(x,n+1)} \\
  &= \sqrt{2^{2n}+x\sqrt{2^{2\left(n+1\right)}+x\sqrt{2^{2\left(n+2\right)}+x\sqrt{...}}}}\\ 
&=\sqrt{4^{n}+x\sqrt{4^{\left(n+1\right)}+x\sqrt{4^{\left(n+2\right)}+x\sqrt{...}}}}\\
\end{aligned}$$

Taking $x=1,n=0$; we get;
$$2=\sqrt{4^{0}+\sqrt{4^{1}+\sqrt{4^{2}+\sqrt{4^{3}+...}}}}$$